# why does PHP_EOL write \r\n at the end of each line

Tags: php, xampp, fwrite, eol, osx-yosemite

I have been struggling with the PHP newline character. I agree with the following facts that PHP_EOL provides a platform neutral newline (\r, \r\n, \n based on OS) and we can leverage that to our benefit.

I am doing a simple PHP File Read and Write in my Mac OS (Yosemite) using XAMPP.

Following is my code to write into a file.

```
$handle = fopen("test.txt", "a+");

$data = "Hello World." . PHP_EOL;

fwrite($handle, $data);
```

The output in the file is given as follows.

```
Hello World.\r\n
```

Note: I had tested this with both fwrite() and file_get_contents(). There is no difference.

My question is : **While writing to a file through write with PHP_EOL, why it writes \r\n at the end of the line?**

I have not problem in inserting a newline (HTML line break) by invoking **nl2br()** function. However, due to this character my HTML output has this \r\n characters!!!

I have been playing around with lot of different alternatives as below

```
$line = str_replace("\r\n","<br/>",$line); // Does NOT work!
$line = preg_replace('~\r?\n~','<br/>', $line); // Works as that of nl2blr()!
$line = str_replace(PHP_EOL, "<br/>",$line); // Works as that of nl2br()!
```

The options above insert a HTML line break but **nothing removes this '\r\n' from the actual text!**

I tested by entering few lines manually (obviously there is no \r\n) and this read method works perfectly without any \r\n. Hence, I concluded that {PHP_EOL + file writing method} could be the culprit!

I am really confused about what am I missing?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why someone down voted this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without the double quotes, PHP doesn't process the special character and should replace as you expect.

`$line = str_replace('\r\n',"<br/>",$line); // note '\r\n' not "\r\n"`

Comment: Thanks. It works. However I have a question. The expert's advise is NOT to replace anything, rather just use nl2br() itself. However, the \r\n is still retained with nl2br()! Any suggestion?

Comment: @itsraghz I think probably somewhere in the encoding or decoding, your EOL characters are being recorded as standard text, not the actual EOL characters (chr 10 and 13). I don't know where this is happening without seeing all your code. The safest way might be like this, replacing `\r\n` with the actual EOL character, and then using in-built `nl2br()` like others suggest:

`$line = nl2br( str_replace( '\r\n', PHP_EOL, $line ) );`

Comment: thanks. Well, it was just a demo/practice where I was reading from a file and I had pasted the crux of it. Let me try your suggestion and come back for any further help!